# What’s causing my budgie’s distended abdomen?

Tags: birds, budgerigar

My budgie’s chest and abdomen are distended. She has lost feathers on her chest as well. When she poops she shakes her tail back and forth as if she is struggling. Her poop is also much bigger than normal. Her behaviour other than that is quite normal, she is chirping, flying around. Picture of budgie with distended abdomen and chest.

[image]

Comment: I would recommend taking her to the vet. People over the internet cannot diagnose something like this.

Comment: How old is she? A pet budgie of mine had a lump on his bottom. It developed when he was about 10 years old and grew bald and distended over time. The vet’s recommendation at the time was to "let him live out his twilight years in peace", given that the lump didn’t bother him.